# how to get total number of rows from mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am writing code for getting total number of records from mysql table(storage engine: InnoDB) and show it on front-end. I am using COUNT(id) for this, like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_count FROM my_table_name
```

but I am getting 6 rows less of total count i.e., I have 73 records totally but I am only getting 67 records as total count. I search for other solutions I found one solution like below:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM my_table_name;
```

but it is throwing mysql Access denied error like "Access denied for user 'my_user_name'@'localhost' to database 'my_table_name'". can anyone tell me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you say there are 73 records? You might have deleted few rows inbetween.

Comment: it will return all rows. you dont need `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and it needs different permissions

Comment: I am watching that particular table directly from phpMyAdmin so that I am able to know that count.

Comment: Try to use `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM my_table_name` query

Comment: @Al-MustafaAzhari count anything without a `WHERE` condition will return count of all rows

Comment: check if phpMyAdmin is returning the correct values. Try using an incognito window and check

Comment: @prasad , you need count of rows with special ID ?

Comment: not any special ID, I just needed total no. of records or rows from the table. storage engine I used for the table is 'InnoDB' I updated my question plz check it once.

Comment: are you sure your table has 73 records? or did you just look at the highest id? There could be some missing ids inbetween (removed). The query looks  fine and it should work. please check again in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Cashbee, yes you are right, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure your table has 73 records? or did you just look at the highest id? There could be some missing ids inbetween (removed). The query looks fine and it should work. please check again in phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

mysql count function will return all the rows if called with argument * like below

```
select count(*) as total from myTable
```

but in case if you provide any column name of your table like

```
 select count(id) as total from myTable
```

then the count of only those rows will be returned which id field is not **NULL**. So may be some of your rows have their **id** field **NULL** that's why the number of row returned by the query is less than actuall.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count FROM my_table_name
```

Maybe not all rows have `id`

Comment: I already have used that first but that also gave the same result after that only I am using COUNT(id) query

Comment: Technically the field ID should be unique, primary and auto increments so SELECT count(id) or SELECT count(*) should return the same value. But if it is not the case count(*) will definitely return total number of rows